# Czech crown or euros/dollars?

Tags: money, exchange, czech-republic

I'm going to travel to Europe in 11 days. I'm going to UK, Austria, Czech Republic and Hungary, and here in Chile I can exchange Chilean pesos to sterling pounds, dollars and euros.
I'm particularly interested in the Czech crown. Do they accept euros or dollars in Czech Republic? What do you recommend, euros or dollars? I'm going to use my credit cards (all contactless), but it's always necessary to carry some cash. I'll be in Czech Republic for two days and a half.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: _Do they accept euros or dollars in Czech Republic_? Do you mean as legal tender or at foreign exchange places?

Comment: @SheikPaul as legal tender :)

Answer (score 5):

It should be easy to find a place to exchange either euros or pounds to local currency both in Czechia and Hungary.

Dollars will work too, but since you need euros and pounds anyway in Austria and the UK, it would just inflate your exchange fee budget for no good reason to do a separate peso-to-dollar transaction.

You *may* be able to get touristy places in Prague to accept euros, but expect to get an abysmal rate for them compared to going to an actual foreign-exchange counter. Pounds or dollars will be worse.

In any case, don't overthink it. If you have only a few days in the country, the loss you make by having local cash left in pocket when you leave will far outweigh whichever small differences in exchange rate margins there are between pounds and euros anyway.

Comment: From my experience,  most shops and restaurants in Prague accept Euros. The rate is usually not the  best but nit terrible.

Comment: My one experience with euros in the Czech Republic, before ATMs made in into the countryside, I got an honest exchange rate at a restaurant. The server even brought over a calculator to show me.